# Изменение значения в ассоциативном массиве. Как лучше?

Tags: ооп, массивы, php

Есть ли какое-нибудь более элегантное и главное быстрое решение данной задачи?
Вот рабочий пример:

```
$array = array(
    array('title' => '1', 'date' => '2014-05-21 13:34:46'),
    array('title' => '2', 'date' => '2014-05-20 13:34:46'),
    array('title' => '3', 'date' => '2014-05-19 13:34:46'),
    array('title' => '4', 'date' => '2014-05-18 13:34:46'),

);
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $date = new DateTime($value['date']);
    $array[$key]['date']=$date->format('d.m.Y');
}
var_dump($array);
```

Прошу обратить внимание на изменение формата даты. С каждым проходом цикла создается по идее новый экземпляр класса. Снижает ли это скорость работы скрипта, если да, то как изменить скрипт?

Comment: Может, как-то так:

    foreach($array as &$item){
        $date = new DateTime($item['date']);
        $item['date'] = $date->format('d.m.Y');
        unset($date);
    }

Comment: @makbeth, данные этого массива, вы случайно не из БД получаете? Если ответ "Да", то почему бы не приводить даты к нужному формату в запросе?

    SELECT `title`, DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%d.%m.%Y') AS `date` FROM `table_name`

Comment: > С каждым проходом цикла создается по идее новый экземпляр класса. Снижает ли это скорость работы скрипта, если да, то как изменить скрипт?

Да, но не сверхдраматично. Такой подход укладывается в концепцию ООП и время, потраченное на создание объектов (скорее всего, там под капотом вообще клонирование) считается за неизбежные издержки.  
Можете при желании измерить время выполнения куска кода с помощью команды `microtime()`, там вряд ли больше одной микросекунды.  
Лично я бы не считал в эом случае дату в финальном формате, а просто передавал массив с объектов DateTime.

Comment: Всем спасибо. Про ссылки я как-то не подумал. Массив наполнил просто для примера (хотя может кому-нибудь и пригодится совет Deonis по поводу DATE_FORMAT). Fike спасибо за пояснение!